# Определение синтаксической связи между словами

Tags: синтаксис

Не могли бы Вы дать точный ответ касательно определения связи между словами в следующем словосочетании:

„Первый хороший человек”?

Казалось бы, здесь приведены обычные определения с главным словом „человек”, однако при рассмотрении смысла сочетания выясняется обратное, поскольку „первый” в данном контексте относится не к человеку, а к целому сочетанию — „первый человек”. Мой вариант разбора:

**(какой?) Первый (кто?) хороший человек**.

Иначе говоря, „хороший человек” я определил бы как подлежащее, а „первый” — как определение. Подлежащее же, в свою очередь, также может быть „раздроблено” на составляющие: „хороший” и „человек”.

Comment: Это предложение? Очень похоже на словосочетание. Для предложения нужен контекст, он у вас есть?

Comment: Как я упомянул выше („... между словами в следующем словосочетании...”), это словосочетание. На самом деле изначально **подобную** конструкцию я встретил, конечно, в составе предложения, но смысл сохранил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например:

*Он **первый хороший человек**, которого я здесь встретил.*

Или: ***Первый хороший челове***к встретился мне здесь.

В синтаксисе мы выделяем такие **структурные единицы**, как слово, словосочетание, предложение.

1) **На уровне словосочетания** мы имеем сложное словосочетание ***первый хороший человек***, причем определение ***первый*** относится к словосочетанию ***хороший человек.***

В то же время это словосочетание не отличается от такого, к примеру, сочетания, как ***большой каменный дом***, то есть **семантика** слов не имеет значения.

2) **На уровне предложения** словосочетание ***хороший человек*** не делится на отдельные слова, а является **единым членом предложения** (подлежащим или именной частью сказуемого). Определение ***первый*** относится к этому словосочетанию.

Здесь уже учитывается **семантика** слов. К примеру,  в предложении *На углу стоял **большой каменный дом*** подлежащим будет только существительное ***дом***.

Comment: Спасибо большое, что дали развёрнутый ответ, ещё и совпадающий с моим мнением. А что, синтаксис действительно не интересуется составом таких сложных единиц, как, например, ПО (либо наш пример)?